# ReportLab Python: Transparent background is changed to black and poor image quality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I am having an issue where I am importing a high-quality PNG image with a transparent background, however when the image is imported to a PDF using ReportLab, the background is changed to black.

Any ideas as to how to prevent this from occurring?

SOLVED: Set mask to 'auto' instead of None.

Second Issue:

The quality of the imported PNG file is significantly lower (very pixelated). How can I import a PNG file while maintaining image quality?

Here is my current code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from PIL import Image

def generatechart(filename):
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=(612,792))
    third = '3B.png'
    tbl = '3BL.png'
    sixh = '6H.png'
    grid = 'grid.png'
    lc = 'LCF.png'
    lf = 'LF.png'
    lfl = 'LFL.png'
    ss = 'SS.png'
    table = 'table.png'
    c.drawImage(third, 86.629, 244.35, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(tbl, 85.042, 272.94, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(sixh, 96.209, 231.464, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(grid, 36.965, 96.518, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(lc, 80.331, 103.487, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(lf, 39.16, 138.452, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(lfl, 36.965, 217.363, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')
    c.drawImage(ss, 104.197, 196.81, width=None, height=None, mask='auto')

    c.showPage()
    c.save()

generatechart('test.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you shoud do is in `drawImage` Method specify the values `width` and `height` less than the original file values. For example: if your file is `width = 1000px` * `height = 1000px` you could be draw the image with `width = 100` * `height = 100`.